# Resource META-INF does not exist

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have tried to convert a regular Java project to an Eclipse plug-in with Tycho, but something went wrong, and I can't figure out what.

These are the problems (I'm just guessing they're related):

- first of all: imports of other projects won't work, even if the other project is in the same workspace
- when I open up the plug-in editor on the "Build" tab, I get the following exception: "Resource '/Project/target/classes/META-INF' does not exist."
- after the multiple error dialogs with above message are gone, the trees of the "Build" tab are completely empty

I have no idea what could help figuring out that problem, so just ask if you have a hunch.

*build.properties*

```
source.. = src/
output.. = target/classes/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .
```

*MANIFEST.MF*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.acme.project;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.2.3.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: ACME
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: [snip]
Import-Package: [snip]
```

How do I fix my plug-ins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons that are completely beyond me, there was the following line in the file  *.settings/org.eclipse.pde.core.prefs* of the project:

```
BUNDLE_ROOT_PATH=target/classes/META-INF
```

I removed it and now everything works.

(To see the file, you need to either use the native file system or disable the ".* resources" filter of the Package Explorer.)

Comment: I just hit the same error and removing `BUNDLE_ROOT_PATH` helped me too. However the error message I got was `Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST my-plugin\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF: Manifest file not found`, so I am posting it here for anyone searching for it. This happened with Tycho 4.0.4.